# xampp delay in mysql startup

Tags: mysql, apache, server, xampp

I have been using xampp for several years but never faced this issue. I have a windows 10 PC with XAMPP installed. When I start XAMPP, the server APACHE starts instantly whereas MySQL takes lot of time to start. I have checked phpmyadmin config.ini file and there host is `127.0.0.1` not localhost. I dont know what checks MySQL performs before it starts. It takes Approximately 5 minutes to start. No problem with queries though. Can anyone help me on this, as I could not find the answer anywhere?

Comment: Is there anything else running on the port? Perhaps it's waiting for that process to shutdown.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I have not checked that part. I will use cports and check. I think I need to restart my PC or atleast log off so that I can identify that process.Thanks.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Sorry I didnt find any. But there is definitely something to do with other software installed in my PC. I will check by uninstalling latest installed softwares.

Comment: Did you run a `netstat` to check?

Comment: I used currports http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but have you started mysql by command line? or
try this one,It can help you: 
**https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28805**

Comment: Sorry I am using windows and on single click of xampp icon both the services start(apache and mysql).